# MSI serviceInstall fails with service failed to start on some machines, but not others

Tags: windows-services, wix, windows-installer

So I have an MSI that deploys a service.

```
        <ServiceInstall Id='ServiceInstall' ErrorControl='ignore' Type='ownProcess' DisplayName='MetricsReportingService' Description='It does metrics reporting' Name='MetricsReportingService' Start='auto' Account='[SERVICEACCOUNT]' Password='[SERVICEACCOUNTPASSWORD]' /> 
        <ServiceControl Id='MetricsReportingService' Remove='uninstall' Name='MetricsReportingService' Start='install' Stop='both' Wait='yes' />
```

When I deploy this service on my own boxes, deployment works great, but when I deploy on another person's machine I get Error 1920, service failed to start.

Now, I'm using the exact same service account and password on both machines (the account has admin permissions on both machines). In fact, I'm using all the same parameters on both machines, but on one it passes and on the other I get that failure.

I don't see any event logging from my service, so it doesn't seem to be making it to my code.

What could be causing this discrepancy?

Comment: You can set Wait='no' to allow the installation to complete before it tries to start the service. That way you can try to start it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing a service for a custom user account you need to make sure that the account has privileges for starting services (it doesn't have them by default). A solution is to set these privileges by using ntrights.exe as a custom action:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276

For example, you can use this command line:

```
ntrights.exe -u [SERVICEACCOUNT] +r SeServiceLogonRight
```

You can also try using a DLL custom action which sets the privileges through custom code. This custom action should run before the service is installed.

Comment: I think this is equivalent for Server 2008 R2. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794944(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my case I also had to add user rights to user. I did it with custom action and [this code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4863/LSA-Functions-Privileges-and-Impersonation). It worked without adding user rights on Win8 and Server 2008 R2. It did not work on Win 7 or Win XP. Hope it helps.